# Keras model to Coreml and using OpenCV

Tags: opencv, keras, coreml

I have a Keras model and have converted it to Coreml successfully. I am passing a colored 50x50 image in RGB format to the model, everything works in my Keras model in Python. However I am really struggling to get the same results in from the Coreml model. I am using OpenCV in my iOS app and need to convert a cv::Mat to a CVPixelBufferRef. I am positive something is not right with my input, but I cannot figure out what it is. The preprocessing for the input that I send into the Python model looks like this

`image = cv2.resize(image, (50, 50))
 image = image.astype("float") / 255.0
 image = img_to_array(image)
 image = np.expand_dims(image, axis=0)`

Any help would be appreciated. Below is the conversion from Keras to Coreml along with its output, and the function to convert a cv::Mat to CVPixelBufferRef (the image here is already resized to 50x50).

**Keras to Coreml conversion**

`coreml_model = coremltools.converters.keras.convert(model, input_names='image', image_input_names='image', output_names='output', class_labels=output_labels, image_scale=1/255.0)`

[image: Output of the Keras to Coreml python script]

**OpenCV Mat to CVPixelBufferRef**

```
int width = 50;//frame.cols;
int height = 50;//frame.rows;

NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                         kCVPixelBufferCGBitmapContextCompatibilityKey,
                         [NSNumber numberWithInt:width], kCVPixelBufferWidthKey,
                         [NSNumber numberWithInt:height], kCVPixelBufferHeightKey,
                         nil];

CVPixelBufferRef imageBuffer;
CVReturn status = CVPixelBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorMalloc, width, height, kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA, (CFDictionaryRef) CFBridgingRetain(options), &imageBuffer);

NSParameterAssert(status == kCVReturnSuccess && imageBuffer != NULL);

CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer, 0);
void *base = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer) ;
memcpy(base, frame.data, frame.total()*4);
CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBuffer, 0);

return imageBuffer;
```

Comment: Usually when this sort of thing happens, your input is in a different format than what the model expects. Since OpenCV loads images in BGR order and your model expects RGB, that's the first place I would look. Perhaps use `kCVPixelFormatType_32RGBA`? Also, it's useful to convert the CVPixelBuffer back to an image to show it on the screen so you can see what it actually looks like.

Comment: Thank you I will give this a shot!

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to load an image with OpenCV and feed it into a Keras model, you need to be extra careful as Keras by default uses PIL to load the image when training. The problem is that PIL loads the image as RGB format whereas OpenCV loads image as BGR format. So if you directly feed the OpenCV image to Keras, you won't get any error but your result will be totally wrong.

As for the solution to this, in Python you can simply use

```
img[...,[0,2]]=img[...,[2,0]]
```

to convert a 3-channel image file between OpenCV format and PIL format.

Comment: Yeah I ran into that issue and got around it. The big issues was the coordinate system in OpenCV and in CoreGraphics is different. (0,0) in a cv::Mat is top left while (0,0) in CoreGraphics is bottom left. I had to convert the image coordinates from cv::Mat to the coordinate system of CoreGraphics.